# how to create an array of interface types

Tags: c#

I have an interface `Vehicle` implemented by a two classes `Car` and `Truck`. how do i create an array of interface type containing a mixture of all the different classes and still be able to access their members, and change them

```
public interface Vehicle
{
    double purchase_price();
    string vehicle_type();
    int release_year();
    int purchase_year();
    bool IsOld(int releaseYear, int purchaseYear);
    void Details();

}
```

In my main method i have this

```
  var vehls = new Vehicle[]
       {
           new Truck(8, 1000, "Ford", "F15000", 2011, 2016, false),
           new Truck(4, 13000, "Ford", "F-150", 2009, 2014, false),
           new Car("Ford", "Super Duty", 2012, 2017, false),
       };
```

when i try to access the car members to assign them it doesn't allow me.
it gives me error.

```
   Car c1 = vehls[2];   
   c1.Wheel = 4;
   c1.Miles = 12000;
```

unless i cast them:

```
   Car c1 = (Car) vehls[2];
   c1.Wheel = 4;
   c1.Miles = 12000;
```

How will i be able to create such an array so that i can still be able to access each class member and fields, without filling everything in the constructor. I don't want to be casting it all the time. Is there a way that the assignment will be able to detect the class type automatic and allow me to access and assign members?

Comment: Trucks also have wheels and mileage.

Comment: Why are you trying to break  Liskov Substitution Principle

Comment: @johnny5 You might want a link, I doubt the OP has any idea what that is

Comment: Aside from anything else, I strongly advise you to learn and follow .NET naming conventions - and consider using properties instead of methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't.

This is the *whole point* of using interfaces (or base classes for that matter), that you only access the derived classes *through the interface*. If you need access to `Wheel` and `Miles` then those members should be part of the interface (as a property).

Downcasting like you are doing is a major code-smell, while you can't *always* avoid it, its a good sign you are doing something the wrong way.

Comment: what is the solution for this, i mean good design would be what?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I don't know your whole domain model so its hard to say. As a commentor pointed out, trucks have wheels and mileage too so for this *exact* code I would just add those two properties to the interface

Comment: Thanks for your comments. so basically all the methods are in the interface and there is no need creating properties for them when implementing them in each class

Comment: @SeekAddo Yes... and no. All public methods/properties (basically) belong in the interface. Implementing classes *still* need those properties in order to conform to the interface though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes, i add all the miles, wheels, and manufacturer in the Interface, and implemented them in the classes. But my point is, all methods are from the interface and there is nothing more for each class to define. is that normal with Interfaces?

Comment: If you are asking if it is normal for classes to not have public members beyond an interface they implement, yes; that is quite common for classes that implement interfaces. This is especially true when the class is a implementation of a Strategy pattern or similar since their only use is going to be through that interface

Comment: I realise the question has much more detail beyond the title, however if one were to simply answer the title and without concern for the wrongs or rights of best practice, it can be achieved. E.g. `var myarray = new List<IMyData>().ToArray();` Don't hate me ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sound more like you have an architecture issue.  According to Liskov Substitution Principle, where ever you are using you're interface you should be treating it like an interface and not trying to downcast it to a specific type.

If you need to handle those issues separately, then either create two lists, and concat them to an interface list later.  Or delegate a better way of handle this, using some factory pattern or adapter pattern etc.

Resource for [Liskov Substition Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Resource for [Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

Comment: @SeekAddo NP, These patterns have always been helpful for designing